# Convert date format in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, format

I have a string of dates in php (`dd/mm/yyyy`) that I want to convert to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I have tried :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `DATE_VAR` = convert(datetime,'19/03/2015', 121) WHERE `ID`=160
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Do not store a date as a text in your db. use a date Format. Also this Looks like mssql query not mysql.

Comment: Also look at STR_TO_DATE, and the manual more generally.

Comment: it's good with Ronak Patel solution, with PHP it's easy !

Comment: You mix MSSQL and MySQL. Which one do you use ?

Comment: You really, really, **really** should be storing your dates as a `DATE` column and leaving the formatting up to your application. Dates stored as strings are nearly useless since they can't be depended on, you have zero date validation and you can't compute differences.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the date conversion in `PHP`. Then one of the solutions could be:

```
$originalDate = str_replace('/', '-', "19/03/2015");
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate)); // This is your mysql compatible date...
```

You can use `$newDate` variable in query.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `DATE_VAR` = '$newDate' WHERE `ID`=160
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it's more easy and it works.

Answer (score 0):

object oriented style:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

where `$date` is the date in *dd/mm/yyyy* format.